# StringIO and csv.reader troubles in python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

I'm trying to read an remote file with fabric. The file is downloading fine into a StringIO. Therefore for new, let's asume the file is locally:

`fd=StringIO('#test=123\nblabla=456').getvalue()`

Now I want to remove the comment and change the value of test at the same time:

```
dict(next(csv.reader([item], delimiter='=', quotechar="'")) for item in next(csv.reader([fd], delimiter='\n', quotechar="'")))
```

I get the error:

`_csv.Error: new-line character seen in unquoted field - do you need to open the file in universal-newline mode?`

But how do I open the file in universal-newline mode?

EDIT:

So, I read the StringIO. But I'm also changing it:

```
content = re.sub(r'(?m)^\#.*\n?', '', fd)  # remove lines starting with #
dict(next(csv.reader([item], delimiter='=', quotechar="'")) for item in next(csv.reader([fd], delimiter='\n', quotechar="'")))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stay within `csv` standard abilities, don't get the value of the `StringIO` file. Just rewind it and pass it to `csv.reader`:

```
fd=StringIO('#test=123\nblabla=456')

fd.seek(0)   # if the file has been written to
d = dict(next(csv.reader([item], delimiter='=', quotechar="'")) for item in next(csv.reader(fd, delimiter='\n', quotechar="'")))
print(d)
```

result:

```
{'#test': '123'}
```

`fd.seek(0)` isn't really needed here, but it's needed if `fd` was written into by some call: you have to rewind the buffer to be able to pass it to `csv.reader`

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It works well when you don't actually do something with the fd. But I also parse it, and then I get TypeError: expected string or buffer on the parsing. So I really need getvalue()

Comment: ok, so define a new variable that holds `fd.getvalue()`: done :) but parsing it + feeding it to csv seems a little strange. You should use parsing done by csv module instead of re-doing a potentially complex parsing.

Comment: argh, You are right, sir! It was really so easy and I was thinking to difficult.